# Google drive API android - Recuperar id de archivo

Tags: java, android, google-drive

buenas tardes, en la mañana hice [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78210/google-drive-api-en-android-no-puedo-lograr-que-este-ejemplo-funcione/78223#78223) y logré guardar una imagen. El problema que se me presenta ahora, es que necesito recuperar el id que le asigna drive a dicha imagen, hay un método que encontré en internet que me da el id, pero es sumamente distinto al método que me otorgaron en mi pregunta pasada:

```
private void createFile(final String filename) {
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(apiClient)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                    writeSampleText(result.getDriveContents());

                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = 
                        new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setTitle(filename)
                            .setMimeType("text/plain")
                            .build();

                    //Opción 1: Directorio raíz
                    DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(apiClient);

                    //Opción 2: Otra carpeta distinta al directorio raiz
                    //DriveFolder folder =
                    //    DriveId.decodeFromString("DriveId:CAESABjKGSD6wKnM7lQoAQ==").asDriveFolder();

                    folder.createFile(apiClient, changeSet, result.getDriveContents())
                        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
                                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Fichero creado con ID = " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
                                } else {
                                    Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error al crear el fichero");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error al crear DriveContents");
                }
            }
        })};
```

el ejemplo lo conseguí de [este enlace](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/google-drive-en-android-1/).
**¿Cómo puedo obtener el id asignado por google drive?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la pregunta que mencionas, [en mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78223/29967) te puse el código oficial de Google para crear un archivo en Drive. Si lo analizas bien, verás que el mismo código muestra, al final, **cómo obtener el id del archivo recién creado** mediante `getDriveId()`:

```
 final private ResultCallback<DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
            ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveFileResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");
                return;
            }
            showMessage("Created a file with content: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
        }
    };
```

Comment: era lo que buscaba, ¡gracias!